# how to position text on an image's center point?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to position text on a image's center point. I've tried this:

```
<span ng-repeat="image in post.postImages" ng-init="image.showDeleteIcon= false" ng-style="{ 'display' : ($index > 3) ? 'none' :'inlne'}" ng-mouseover="image.showDeleteIcon=true" ng-mouseleave="image.showDeleteIcon=false">
  <a id="{{$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" onclick="SetDataGallery(this.id)" ng-href="../upload/post-photos/{{image.attachmentURL}}">
    <img class="img-responsive feed-photo" ng-src="../upload/post-photos/{{image.attachmentURL}}" alt="Photo" style="display:inline;" ng-style="{ 'opacity' : ($index == 3 && post.postImages.length > 4) ? '0.5' : '1' }">
    <a href="#" class="imgDelete" ng-if="post.timelineStrore.hasControl" ng-show="image.showDeleteIcon" title="Delete Photo" ng-click="DeletePostAttachment(post.timelineStrore.id, image.postAttachmentId,'image')">
      <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </a>
    <i class ="imgcounter" style="color: #23527c;cursor: pointer !important;font-family:Times, Times New Roman;font-style:normal;font-size:50px;" ng-if="post.postImages.length - 4 > 0 && $index == 3" id="{{$parent.$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" onclick="$('#' + this.id).click();"> + {{post.postImages.length - 4}}</i>
  </a>
</span>
```

and my css:

```
.imgcounter {
  z-index: 500;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 45 px;
  position: absolute;
  color: tomato;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  margin-left: -120 px;
}
```

It's working, but not on different size of images like below:

[image: 1st image]
[image: 2nd pic]

The text is showing, but based on image size the text is not properly positioned.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, hardcoding specific values like you're doing isn't going to work for arbitrary sizes.

There are [lots and lots of techniques](http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) for centering elements vertically (horizontally is trivial). Here's a simple one:

```css
span {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.imgcounter {
  font-size: 40px;
  color:#FFF;
  
  z-index:2;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* <-- here 50% refers to the size of .imgcounter */
  top:50%; left:50%; /* <-- here the 50% measures the containing span */
}
```

```html
<span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/150">
    <i class="imgcounter">X</i>
</span>

<span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/350">
    <i class="imgcounter">TEXT</i>
</span>

<span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/350">
    <i class="imgcounter">23%</i>
</span>
```

Incidentally there are a number of other problems with your code, most prominently you can't nest `<a>` tags inside each other like you're doing, and you should make up your mind whether to put your css inline or in a .css file. (Put it in a .css file.)